Maximum number of pairs of vectors such that $\langle v_i , v_j \rangle \neq 0 $
Let $\langle \cdot  , \cdot \rangle $ denote the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^7$ . Let $\Sigma =\{ v_1 , v_2 , ..., v_5 \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^7 $ be a set of unit vectors such that $\langle v_i , v_j \rangle $ is a non-positive integer for all $1\le i \neq j \le 5$ . Define $ N(\Sigma )$ to be the number of pairs $( r , s) , 1\le r ,s \le 5$ such that $\langle v_r , v_s \rangle \neq 0$ . The maximum possible value of $ N (\Sigma)$ is equal to
(a) 9
(b)10
(c)14
(d)5
I know there are similar question but I found none of them satisfactory .
The first thing that comes to mind is to produce such a set of $5$ vectors where the vectors are in pairwise negative dot products but couldn't come up with such a set . The standard bases vectors gives $N(\Sigma)=5$
I know if $\langle v_i , v_j \rangle < 0 $ for all $i\neq j $ ranging from $1$ to $5$ then any subset consisting of $4$ vectors become L.I using the standard  technique of dividing coefficients into positive and negative part . But unsure again how to use this fact .
Another way might be a cheating if I assume the cardinality of the largest set $S$ (say) where pairwise dot product of vectors in the set  $S$ is non-zero (hence negative ) to be $n$ .
Then basically we are using the value from the options and solving the quadratic $n^2-n+10-2a=0 ,a$ from the options, for non-negative integer $n$ or am I talking rubbish here ?
Hints Please.

Perhaps you meant $r<s$? Right now if $r,s$ works with $r\neq s$ then $r \mapsto s$, $s \mapsto r$ also naturally works.

Like obviously if $<vr,vs> \neq 0$ then $<vs,vr> \neq 0$, but I would imagine you meant to write $r<s$ as to not double count?

@Intelligentipauca May I know the technique/algorithm of producing that set of vectors ?

@Snared Hmmm yes basically we can talk about the ordered pair here .

@user-492177 Am I understanding it right, or would the only possible values of $\langle v_i, v_j\rangle$ be $0$ or $-1$? Since they are required to be non-positive integers and $v_i$'s are unit vectors so $|\langle v_i, v_j\rangle| \leq 1$

@TrevorNorton  I dont think so cause the negative inner products does't have to be absolutely bounded by $1$ .

@Intelligentipauca Some of the pairwise inner products of your vectors are not integers .

@user-492177 The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $|\langle v_i, v_j\rangle| \leq | v_i| \cdot |v_j|$, so if the vectors have length 1 then the inner product cannot be less than -1. Is the question written correctly? If the inner products need to be integers, then the answers don't make sense to me.

@TrevorNorton Yes the question is written correctly.  Its a Phd entrance question from India (GATE) . Anyway , how does your boundedness for the inner product imply logical  fallacy in question ? Can you elaborate?

@TrevorNorton I have added the image of original question

@user-492177 Oh I was counting only pairs with $i<j$. If we count all pairs of $i,j$ then it does make sense, sorry. I don’t have time to write up the answer, but I think the answer will be (a). Hint: consider the standard basis and the negatives of those vectors.

I suggest just enumerating $N(\Sigma)$ based on the number of linearly independent vectors in $\Sigma$ which I'll call rank.  $\text{rank } \Sigma = 5 \implies  N(\Sigma)=5$ and $\text{rank } \Sigma = 4 \implies  N(\Sigma)=7$ and...

Sorry, I missed the "integer" requirement. I'll delete my comment.

Hints towards a solution
Show that

$\langle v_i, v_j \rangle \in \{ 0, -1 \}$ for $ i \neq j$ .
What does it mean if $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = -1$?
What does that suggest we do with these vectors?  Show that we can do this.
Thus the answer is $ 5 + 2\lfloor \frac{ 5 -1 } { 2 } \rfloor = 9$.


With regards to the side note (which is irrelevant to the problem), show that in $ \mathbb{R}^d$, the maximum number of vectors with pairwise negative (not necessarily integer) dot products is $d+1$. For a construction, take the vertices of a pyramid.

Just to clarify I am understanding things properly. The second bullet point just indicates that $v_j$ has to $-v_i$ . In the third bullet point , I assume you mean we can pair up unit vectors with their negative ? Can you please elaborate a bit ?

Can you please also give motivation behind consideration of this kind of system of vectors and suggest some references ?

Yup you got the gist. Note that you do have to ensure that there is no $v_I = v_J$ so that the pairing is unique. $\quad$ I'm not aware of any motivation behind this. It's a somewhat forced scenario / way to hide that the dot product is -1.
